# How can I fix the error with json_object in postgresql-9.6?

Tags: json, postgresql, zabbix, postgresql-9.6

There is Zabbix with PostgreSQL database monitoring. There is one trigger in Zabbix that constantly spam error:

```
ERROR:  function json_object(text[], text[]) does not exist
LINE 11:    SELECT json_object(array_agg(name), array_agg(setting)) F...
                           ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 190
```

Found a template in which this trigger is registered. It is standard, I tried to request a line separately in Postgres, as a result the same error.
The request itself:

```
select json_build_object('extensions',(select array_agg(extname) from (select extname from pg_extension order by extname) as e),'settings', (select json_object(array_agg(name),array_agg(setting)) from (select name,setting from pg_settings where name != 'application_name' order by name) as s));
```

I ask you to tell what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `json_object(text[], text[])` exists in PostgreSQL ([documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html)) since version 9.4. 
Are you sure you use the version 9.4 or above ? You can check with:

```
SELECT version();
```

Comment: Thanks. My mistake. Although I installed version 9.6, but it shows version 9.2. Apparently something was wrong.