# create a json column from some rows by SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use SQL (Spark SQL 3.0, databricks runtime 7.0) to create a new table from an existing table.
I would like to aggregate some rows of one specific column into a json column in the new table.

The existing table

```
id,     year,  month, val
u_ced    2002   05    v_scyronc
u_ced    2002   05    v_ytbtbdv
u_ced    2002   05    v_utncasx
u_pny    2005   07    v_opcrgae
u_pny    2005   07    v_wytnecs
```

I need a new table like

```
id,       val_json
u_ced     {{"shown": true, "val_id": "v_scyronc" },
          {"shown": true, "val_id": "v_ytbtbdv" },
          {"shown": true, "val_id": "v_utncasx" },
          {"shown": true, "val_id": "v_opcrgae" },
          {"shown": true, "val_id": "v_wytnecs" }
         }} 

 u_pny    {{"shown": true, "val_id": "v_opcrgae" },
          {"shown": true, "val_id": "v_wytnecs" }              
         }}
```

I think I need a "group by" but I do not know how to create the json column.

I have tried:

```
SELECT json_object(array_agg(id), array_agg(val))
```

But, I got error:

```
 Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'json_object'. 
  This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'
```

Hope that anyone can help me about this.

thanks

Comment: Check your postgresql version like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59983353/how-can-i-fix-the-error-with-json-object-in-postgresql-9-6). I know this is not your main problem, but the message error is before your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is useful-

```scala
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()

    /**
      * +-----+-----+------+---------+
      * |id,  |year,|month,|val      |
      * +-----+-----+------+---------+
      * |u_ced|2002 |5     |v_scyronc|
      * |u_ced|2002 |5     |v_ytbtbdv|
      * |u_ced|2002 |5     |v_utncasx|
      * |u_pny|2005 |7     |v_opcrgae|
      * |u_pny|2005 |7     |v_wytnecs|
      * +-----+-----+------+---------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- id,: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- year,: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- month,: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- val: string (nullable = true)
      */

    df.withColumn("shown", lit(true))
      .withColumnRenamed("val", "val_id")
      .withColumn("val_json", struct(col("shown"), col("val_id")))
      .groupBy("id")
      .agg(collect_list("val_json").as("val_json"))
      .select(col("id"), to_json(col("val_json")).as("val_json"))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +-----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |id   | val_json                                                                                      |
      * +-----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |u_pny|[{"shown":true,"val_id":"v_opcrgae"},{"shown":true,"val_id":"v_wytnecs"}]                                    |
      * |u_ced|[{"shown":true,"val_id":"v_scyronc"},{"shown":true,"val_id":"v_ytbtbdv"},{"shown":true,"val_id":"v_utncasx"}]|
      * +-----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      */
```

Answer (score 0):

Spark SQL does not has a function 'json_object'.

see this [spark sql built-in functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html).

function`to_json`,`collect_list` and `concat_ws` might be useful.